# Drupal 9 - Allow access to a page only from a specific domain

Tags: file, content-management-system, drupal-8, drupal-9, drupal-entities

How to allow access to a Drupal file/page only from a specific domain?

I have tried php filter module but enabling this module can cause security and performance issues as it allows users to execute PHP code on your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an AccessChecker on your specific route and  check if the domain is the correct one.

In your_module.services.yml :

```
  your_module.domain_access_checker:
    class: Drupal\your_module\Access\DomainAccessChecker
    tags:
      - { name: access_check, applies_to: _acces_domain }
```

In your_module.routing.yml:

```
your_module.mypage:
  path: '/my-path'
  defaults:
    _title: 'My page'
    _controller: '\Drupal\your_module\Controller\MyController::show'
  requirements:
    _acces_domain : 'TRUE'
```

And finaly in your DomainAccessChecker.php:

```
  public function access(Route $route, RouteMatchInterface $route_match, AccountInterface $account) {
    $domainIsCorrect = your_code_here;
    if ($domainIsCorrect) {
      return AccessResult::allowed();
    }
    return AccessResult::forbidden();
  }
```